# Parent, child and return types in Java

Tags: java, object

I am relatively new to Java. I have scenario where I want to return a child type object when a parent type of object is expected.

Sample Java code:

Parent def:

```
public class parentclass {

    private String token;
    private String userId;

   public parentclass(String token, String userId)
    {
        this.token = token;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

Child 1 def:

```
public class childclass1 extends parentclass {

    public String dept;

    public childclass1(String token, String userId, String dept)
    {
        super(token, userId, dept);
    }
    //more code as needed
}
```

Child 2 def:

```
public class childclass2 extends parentclass {
     public String college;

    public childclass2(String token, String userId, String college)
    {
        super(token, userId, college);
    }
   //more code as needed
}
```

Caller:

```
public class1{

public parentclass verify_method(String Auth1, String Auth2) {
                if (a)
                 return login1(Auth1);
                else
                 return login2(Auth2);
    
  }
}
```

Called:

```
public class2{
public childclass1 login1(String Auth){
       //Do something 
       return childclass1;
    }
    
public childclass2 login2(String Auth){

       //Do something 
       return childclass2;
    }
}
```

In above example, my caller is erroneous as return object type do not match. Please advise how do I modify the code so that I could achieve what I wanted..

Comment: This `super(token, userId, dept);` won't compile.

Comment: Ok, any recommendation on my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The parent constructor only have two fields, you'll have to put the child-class field separately, like this:

```
    public childclass1(String token, String userId, String dept)
    {
        super(token, userId);
        this.dept = dept;          
    }
```